# Issues setting SDP on dockerized FreeSWITCH

Tags: docker, rtp, freeswitch, sdp

I'm running a FreeSWITCH inside a docker container. I need the SDP information to be sent out to reference the IP address of the docker host. I have this internal profile define on FreeSWITCH:

```
freeswitch@36fe182d8fb3> sofia status profile internal
=================================================================================================
Name                internal
Domain Name         N/A
Auto-NAT            false
DBName              sofia_reg_internal
Pres Hosts          0.0.0.0,0.0.0.0
Dialplan            XML
Context             public
Challenge Realm     auto_from
RTP-IP              CONTAINER_IP_ADDRESS
Ext-RTP-IP          HOST_IP_ADDRESS
SIP-IP              CONTAINER_IP_ADDRESS
Ext-SIP-IP          HOST_IP_ADDRESS
URL                 sip:mod_sofia@HOST_IP_ADDRESS:5060
BIND-URL            sip:mod_sofia@HOST_IP_ADDRESS:5060;maddr=CONTAINER_IP_ADDRESS;transport=udp,tcp
WS-BIND-URL         sip:mod_sofia@CONTAINER_IP_ADDRESS:5066;transport=ws
WSS-BIND-URL        sips:mod_sofia@CONTAINER_IP_ADDRESS:7443;transport=wss
HOLD-MUSIC          local_stream://moh
OUTBOUND-PROXY      N/A
CODECS IN           OPUS,G722,PCMU,PCMA,VP8
CODECS OUT          OPUS,G722,PCMU,PCMA,VP8
TEL-EVENT           101
DTMF-MODE           rfc2833
CNG                 13
SESSION-TO          0
MAX-DIALOG          0
NOMEDIA             false
LATE-NEG            true
PROXY-MEDIA         false
ZRTP-PASSTHRU       true
AGGRESSIVENAT       false
CALLS-IN            0
FAILED-CALLS-IN     0
CALLS-OUT           0
FAILED-CALLS-OUT    0
REGISTRATIONS       0
```

Given this profile I'd expect `c=IN IP4 HOST_IP_ADDRESS` however this is what's sent:

```
v=0
o=FreeSWITCH 1522401421 1522401423 IN IP4 CONTAINER_IP_ADDRESS
s=FreeSWITCH
c=IN IP4 CONTAINER_IP_ADDRESS
t=0 0
m=audio 16390 RTP/AVP 0 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv
```

How can I make sure FreeSWITCH sends `c=IN IP4 HOST_IP_ADDRESS` instead of `c=IN IP4 CONTAINER_IP_ADDRESS`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think your FreeSwitch is behind SIP proxy.
If yes, then need configure ACL and update "local-network-acl" variable of SIP profile. Example

```
<param name="local-network-acl" value="loopback.auto"/>
```